# Matrix-free Arnoldi method for eigensystems

Tags: linear-algebra, sparse-arrays

I am solving a generalized eigenvalue problem

$$\mathbf S\,\mathbf x = \lambda\,\mathbf M\,\mathbf x$$

w/ $\mathbf S := \mathbf B\,\mathbf A^{-1}\,\mathbf B^{T}$, and $\mathbf A$ is a sparse matrix (SparseArray[]):

```
S = B.Inverse@A.Transpose@B;
Eigenvalues[{S, M}, 1, Method -> "Arnoldi"]
```

The problem is, computing `Inverse@A` is not feasible already for the matrix size 32 736 ($\mathbf A^{-1}$ is dense and takes ~8.5 gigabytes). I do not really need $\mathbf A^{-1}$ explicitly for the iterative Arnoldi method, and in principle I can approximate its action e.g. via a preconditioned Krylov solver.

Is there a way to do this? I.e. instead of passing $\mathbf S$ to `Eigenvalues[]` pass something that mimics multiplication of $\mathbf S$ by a vector.

Comment: I think the title on this could be a bit more descriptive of what your specific issue is. Maybe something like `"Solving generalized Eigenvalue problems with SparseArray"?

Comment: Well, there is `LinearSolve[A]` which is the practical alternative to `Inverse[A]` for large matrices. I don't know if you can throw that into `Eigenvalues`, but it's a start.

Comment: @sjoerd-smit Seems like `Eigenvalues[]` does not accept `LinearSolveFunction[]`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know an Anoldi imeplementation in Mathematica that allows a function that computes a matrix-vector as instead of a matrix itself as argument. It would be great to have one (therefore +1 for bringing this up). If $\mathbf{A}$ is a dense matrix of size $32 736 \times 32 736$, that's really bad anyway. Do you have a very good preconditioner for it? In general, we need much more context. Where does $A$ come from? Maybe there is some structure that can be exploited. What are $\mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{M}$? Maybe their inverses are easier to compute?

Comment: @henrik-schumacher $\mathbf A$ itself is sparse; $\mathbf A^{-1}$ is not. It comes from Trace/Cut FEM discretization of the surface Stokes problem, so $\mathbf A$ is a surface vector Laplace block, $-\mathbf B$/$\mathbf B^{T}$ are divergence/gradient blocks, and $\mathbf M$ is a pressure mass matrix. All of them are sparse and a good preconditioner for $\mathbf A$ is available.

Comment: Hm. I see. So you really need only a matrix-free Arnoldi routine. Unfortunately, _Mathematica_ is shipped without one (to my knowledge). =(  You would have to use _Library Link_ to a library that is capable of doing this, for example the ["Extended Eigensolver Interface"](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-fortran-extended-eigensolver-interfaces-for-extremal-eigenvalues-singular-values) provided by Intel MKL.

Comment: In the case $\mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{B}=I$ you can reduce you problem to $\mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{x}=\lambda\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{M}\mathbf{x}$